# Dynamically require vendor module with webpack

Tags: webpack

Normally, with static requires or imports (CommonJS/ES imports), webpack can require any module from /node_modules/, for example:

```
var vendorModule = require('vendor-module');
```

But I want to dynamically load a module from /node_modules/ like:

```
var vendorModuleId = 'vendor-module';

...

var vendorModule = require(vendorModuleId);
```

This doesn't work because webpack can't determine the dependency at compile time and it's obviously insane to include all of /node_modules/ in the bundle just in case we might want to dynamically load some vendor module.

I'm looking for a way to trick webpack into resolving these modules *dynamically*. Preferably by telling webpack which modules in /node_modules/ should be included in the bundle via the webpack config file.

Some people say the ContextReplacementPlugin can be useful for these situations, but I can't understand how.

Anybody have any idea how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: After creating the bundle - you need to contain these modules in it? Or you need to lazy load these modules if necessary?

Comment: Lazy load would be nice as an option, but is not required

Answer (score 3):

You can make a file for import and export needed modules via loaders.

1. Create an empty file "./vendors.js";
2. `npm install exports-loader imports-loader --save-dev`
3. In `webpack.config.js`:

   ```
   // config needed vendor modules
   var vendorModules = [
       'one', 'two', 'three', 'vendor-module'
   ];

   ...

   module.exports = {
   ...
       loaders: [{ // Add loader
           include: require.resolve('./vendors.js'),
           loader: 'imports-loader?' + vendorsModules.map(function(module, index) {
               return 'dep' + index + '=' + module;
           }).join(',') + '!exports-loader?' + vendorsModules.map(function(module, index) {
               return module + '=dep' + index;
           }).join(',')
       },...]
       ...
   }
   ```
4. In module where you need to require vendor:

   ```
   // import * as vendorsModules from './vendors';
   var vendorsModules = require('./vendors');

   var vendorModuleId = 'vendor-module';
   ...
   var vendorModule = vendorsModules[vendorModuleId];
   console.log('module', vendorModule);
   ```

It will adds configured vendors to your bundle. If you need to lazy load these modules, you need to do more complex modules factory using `require.resolve` and promise-like interface for getting needed module.

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks! I've also noticed that there's a new option added to the ContextReplacementPlugin that accepts a pre-defined map. Both options worth checking out.

Comment: @martijnboland I suppose yes - https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/context . If I check solution before you, I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

[Webpack now supports dynamic loading](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports), example:

```
// js
const _ = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "lodash" */ 'lodash')

// webpack.config.js
output: {
  filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
},
```

That snippet is assuming you also have the [Syntax Dynamic Import Babel Plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-dynamic-import/#installation).

Comment: How do you accomplish this with multiple named exports ie. `import {func1, func2, func3} from 'npm-module'`

Answer (score 0):

You can reference a module path dynamically using [dynamic loading](https://survivejs.com/webpack/techniques/dynamic-loading/#dynamic-paths-with-a-dynamic-import):

```
// module.js
export default {
  init: () => console.log('module.init'),
};

// index.js
const id = 'module';
import(`./${id}.js`).then(obj => obj.default.init());
```